# Given $w=w(z)$ is conformal, what is $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z\partial \bar z}\log(w_z\bar w_{\bar z})$?

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, derivatives

Let $z$ belong to some open subset of $\mathbb C$ and $w=w(z)$ a conformal map, i.e. holomorphic with nonzero derivative everywhere. What is $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z\partial \bar z}\log(w_z\bar w_{\bar z})$, where $w_z=\frac{\partial w}{\partial z}$, and similar for $\bar w_{\bar z},w_{\bar z},\bar w_z$.

**My attempt:**
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z\partial \bar z}\log(w_z\bar w_{\bar z})
=\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar z}\log(w_z\bar w_{\bar z})
=\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\frac{w_{z\bar z}\bar w_{\bar z}+w_z\bar w_{\bar z\bar z}}{w_z\bar w_{\bar z}}$$
Note that $w_z$ is holomorphic w.r.t. $z$, hence $w_{z\bar z}=0$. Continue the computation above:
$$=\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\frac{\bar w_{\bar z\bar z}}{\bar w_{\bar z}}=\frac{\bar w_{\bar z\bar zz}\bar w_{\bar z}-\bar w_{\bar z\bar z}\bar w_{\bar zz}}{(\bar w_{\bar z})^2}$$
Again note that $\bar w_{\bar z\bar z}$ and $\bar w_{\bar z}$ are both holomorphic w.r.t. $\bar z$, hence
$$\bar w_{\bar z\bar zz}=0,\quad\bar w_{\bar zz}=0$$
Conclusion:
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z\partial \bar z}\log(w_z\bar w_{\bar z})=0$$
Is there any flaw in this proof?

Comment: Your proof looks good. You could have even stopped earlier, since $\frac{\bar{w}_{\bar{z}\bar{z}}}{\bar{w}_{\bar{z}}}$ was already holomorphic w.r.t. $\bar{z}$

Comment: @NinadMunshi Thanks. I missed that.